# How to get url parameters values from HTTPRequest in Apache HTTPClient

Tags: query-string, httpclient

I would like to take value of specific parameter in query string. Is there any method in HttpClient which can do if for me (ex. util class method) or I have to write my own?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 4.X.X there is:

```
    List<NameValuePair> parameters = URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(
                request.getRequestLine().getUri()), HTTP.UTF_8);

        for (NameValuePair nameValuePair : parameters) {
            System.out.println(nameValuePair.getName() + ": "
                    + nameValuePair.getValue());
        }
```

Then handle your own parameter.

Comment: There's no such method signature for `URLEncodedUtils.parse`, and `HTTP.UTF_8` is deprecated. Try `URLEncodedUtils.parse(new URI(request.getRequestLine().getUri()).getQuery(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`.